# Adding class to first dynamically created li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating `<li>` elements as shown below from some JSON response. The problem with the following creation is that I have fixed and same number of bootstrap classes defined for each `<li>` element.

If I want to add the `class="active"` in the first `<li>` tag and not in the remaining tags so that the declaration would look like the following for the first list element :

```
<li role="presentation" class = "active" >.
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

```
for (var key in jsonData) {
           if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             console.log(key + " -> " + jsonData[key].textName);
                
    $('#tabs').append('<li role="presentation" ><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab_'+jsonData[key].textName+'" href="#panel_'+jsonData[key].textName+'">'+jsonData[key].textName+'<span id="count_'+jsonData[key].textName+'" class="countLabel"></span></a></li>');
                                   
        }
                        
    }
```

Comment: What does jsonData look like?

Comment: Have you tried....counting? Sorry but i mean....what are you asking?
@CarstenLøvboAndersen it's an object, since when do object properties always start with 0?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Sorry hit enter too soon. i just wanted to ask you, why the first property would be a 0 in this case. he can't do it that way, he has to use an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it and just use .first()

```js
$('#tabs').html(
  Object.entries(jsonData).map(([key,value]) => `<li role="presentation">
    <a data-toggle="tab" id="tab_${value.textName}" href="#panel_${value.textName}">${value.textName}<span id="count_${value.textName}" class="countLabel"></span></a>
  </li>`).join("")
).first().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's better to use `Object.keys` to transform the object into an array and then use `Array.forEach` to perform an action on each member.

This has the advantage of giving you access to the index of the item being transformed. You can then check if the index is 0 and add the active class to the element.

```js
const jsonData = {
  foo: {
    textName: 'foo'
  },
  bar: {
    textName: 'bar'
  }
}

Object.keys(jsonData).forEach((key, index) => {
  $('#tabs').append(`<li role="presentation" class="${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}">${jsonData[key].textName}</li>`);
})
```

```css
.active {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not show what the json data looks like (e.g if its an array you could use `map()` method), The solution is to create a variable that holds the index and increment it on each loop or at least once.

```
var index = 0;    
for (var key in jsonData) {
   if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + jsonData[key].textName);
       if(index == 0){         
    $('#tabs').append('<li role="presentation" class="active">');
    index = 3;
          }else{
    $('#tabs').append('<li role = "presentation">');
      }            
    $('tabs').append('<a data-toggle="tab" id="tab_'+jsonData[key].textName+'" href="#panel_'+jsonData[key].textName+'">'+jsonData[key].textName+'<span id="count_'+jsonData[key].textName+'" class="countLabel"></span></a></li>');            
        }
                        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
let isFirstRun = true, container = $('#tabs'); //cache container for better performance
for (var key in jsonData) {
  if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    container.append('<li role="presentation" ' + (isFirstRun ? 'class="active" : ""') + ' ><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab_' + jsonData[key].textName +
      '" href="#panel_' + jsonData[key].textName + '">' + jsonData[key].textName + '<span id="count_' + jsonData[
        key].textName + '" class="countLabel"></span></a></li>');
    isFirstRun = false;
  }
}
```